# get data from other rows based on content from another row

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data that may look as follows. Answers are always submitted in a block of 6 from a user. If someone has answered "1" for questionID 1 then I need to know what they answered for question4 for example, or if they answered 1 for question 2 then I need their answer to question 5 and if they answered 1 to question 3 I need their answer to question 6.

```
user   questionID    response
1      1             2
1      2             3
1      3             1
1      4             5
1      5             5
1      6             2
2      1             1
2      2             6
2      3             3
2      4             3
2      5             2
2      6             5
```

I could really do with some help on this one. Many thanks

Comment: Use a `CASE`... do you care about responses to questions 4, 5 or 6?

Comment: 4,5 and 6 are related to questions 1,2 and 3, so if my criteria is a response of 1 to question 1,2 or 3 then I need the related response from question 4,5 or 6. Is that in any way clear? It's really difficult to explain!

Comment: And if the user not answered 1 in q 1, 2 and 3, what do you need?

Comment: In that case there would be no data to report on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need? Try to run this query.

```
select u1.*, u2.response from users u1
left join users u2
on u1.user = u2.user and u1.questionID = u2.questionID - 3
where u1.response = 1
```

---

**substring('inp1' FROM 4) gives 1:**

```
select u1.*, u2.response from users u1
left join users u2
on u1.user = u2.user and
  substring(u1.questionID FROM 4) = substring(u2.questionID FROM 4) - 3
where u1.response = 1
```

Comment: I think this is doing exactly what I need, thank you so much! I just had to add in a little more in the where clause to check only for questions 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Aaargh! I have just found out that questionID is NOT an integer but is in fact a string with values inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5, inp6. Is ther any way to amend your quesry?

Comment: If questionID are strings like 'inp1', then you need to get just numbers from then. You could do it with a SUBSTRING function. I added new query, try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a "pivot", where you get all answers together:

```
select
  t1.response as response1,
  t2.response as response2,
  t3.response as response3,
  t4.response as response4,
  t5.response as response5,
  t6.response as response6
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t1.user = t2.user and t2.questionId = 2
left join mytable t3 on t1.user = t3.user and t3.questionId = 3
left join mytable t4 on t1.user = t4.user and t4.questionId = 4
left join mytable t5 on t1.user = t5.user and t5.questionId = 5
left join mytable t6 on t1.user = t6.user and t6.questionId = 6
where t1.user = ?
```

I would make this a view and add `t1.user` as a column, then you could just select from view where user = ?.